# Hide status bar while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, statusbar

iOS 8 adds a super new cool feature: hiding the navigation bar when user is scrolling.

This with a single line in `viewDidload` :

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Cool, isn't it?

But now I have a little problem: when the navigation bar is hidden, the status bar is still here and overlaps content, which is ugly.

What should I do to make it hidden when the navigation bar is hidden?

Comment: hey, did you ever find out how to do this? thanks!

Comment: No unfortunately...could you add +1 ?

Comment: Take a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870382/how-to-prevent-status-bar-from-overlapping-content-with-hidesbarsonswipe-set-on

Comment: Thanks but it s obj c solution and I am really new to dev also only understand swift language . It s hard to translate it to swift version. Could you help me doing this ?

Answer (score 14):

Override the following methods on UIViewController:

```
extension MyViewController {
  override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return barsHidden // this is a custom property
  }

  // Override only if you want a different animation than the default
  override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
  }
}
```

Update `barsHidden` somewhere in the code and call
`setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed problem for in Xcode 6.1

> navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true

Comment: i just want to hide the status bar when the navigationBar is hidden. How to monitor this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this answer on some comments on [this post](http://natashatherobot.com/navigation-bar-interactions-ios8/), which are speculation. I am not sure if this will work, because Apple does not give us any direct way or delegate method for when the navigation bar hides.

Subclass UINavigationBar as NavigationBar. Add a property observer to its `hidden` property like so:

```
var hidden: Bool{
didSet{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(self.hidden, animation: .Slide)
}
}
```

You want to then go to your `viewDidLoad` method in your main view controller, and set your `self.navigationBar` property (or `self.navigationController.navigationBar`, not sure which one) to an instance of your new NavigationBar class.

Note that I cannot test this right now, let me know how/if this works.

Comment: It doesn't. Where do i have to put the var hidden declaration ? self.navigationController.navigationBar give me "UINavigationController does not have a member called navigationBar".  self.navigationBar give me "myTableViewController does not have a member called navigationBar"

Comment: @jmcastel Doesn't UINavigationController have a navigation bar? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/navigationBar

Answer (score 0):

You could detect swipes by using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. I'm using it on UIWebView:

In viewDidLoad I have:

```
let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipe")
let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didSwipe")
swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

I also have an extension to my viewcontroller, called WebViewViewController:

```
extension WebViewViewController {
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return hideStatusBar
    }

    override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide
    }
}
```

On a class level in my WebViewViewController I also have:

```
var hideStatusBar = false

func didSwipe() {
    hideStatusBar = true   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I spent all day doing this, hopefully this helps some people out. There's a `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer`. So you could make a listener for the corresponding `UIPanGesture`, noting that if the navigation bar is hidden then its y origin is -44.0; otherwise, it's 0 (not 20 because we hid the status bar!).

In your view controller:

```
 // Declare at beginning
var curFramePosition: Double!
var showStatusBar: Bool = true
self.navigationController?.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "didSwipe:")

...

override func viewDidLoad(){
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
  curFramePosition = 0.0 // Not hidden
  self.navigationController?.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "didSwipe:")
  ...
}

func didSwipe(swipe: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    // Visible to hidden
    if curFramePosition == 0 && self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y == -44 {
        curFramePosition = -44
        showStatusBar = false
        prefersStatusBarHidden()
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
    // Hidden to visible
    else if curFramePosition == -44 && self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y == 0 {
        curFramePosition = 0
        showStatusBar = true
        prefersStatusBarHidden()
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    if showStatusBar{
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```