# Display nav bar when user scrolls down - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have created a parallax detail view in swift. Wish to allow nav bar colour and title display when user scrolls down.

Like this example here on the detail view. This is in objective C and I can't figure out the swift version. I'm sure it's simple enough with a few lines of code in the right place.

https://github.com/KMindeguia/movies/blob/master/README.md

I know the nav bar has a .hideswhenuserswips function but can't find anything for this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use storyboard for your UINavigationController, you can set like this [image: set on storyboard]

Or, you can set in your code like this:

```
myNavigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollview delegate` methods to show or hide navigation bar.

you can implement `scrollViewDidScroll` , `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` or `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating`.

from this delegate methods you can manage your navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks so I can just set navigationBar.hidden = false but scrolling but how would I get the navigation bar to show only after the top uiimage is out of sight. (Like the example I linked)

Answer (score 0):

This component just using simple UIView and implementing UIScrollViewDelegate methods. You can add your custom view in top of parent view and hide it, implement UIScrollViewDelegate methods and track some contentOffset of uiscrollview. Like in this component from lines 237 

[scrollDelegate methods](https://github.com/KMindeguia/movies/blob/master/Movies/UI/Details%20Page%20View/KMScrollingHeaderView.m)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `NavigationBar` in each `viewcontroller`, if you would not show `navigationbar` use this code,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

And show the `navigationbar` in particular `viewController` put this below code,

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
```

this lines used your method, or you use this code,

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

when scrolling to show your navigationbar see this link [Hide status bar while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197260/hide-status-bar-while-scrolling)

hope its helpful