# Animate UIStatusBar ios9+ (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I'm trying to animate the status bar based on the scroll direction of my scroll view. Currently, I am able to hide the status bar, however I can't get the change to animate.

I thought there was a method that  did handled this, considering one exists for the navigation bar, and I found the method `setStatusBarHidden(_:with:)`, however this method appears to have been deprecated since ios9.

Right I am setting the status in an animation block and calling `.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` as seen below

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }, completion: { (completed) in
            })
        }
```

One other thing, is it still possible to set the animation style? Before, using the `setStatusBarHidden` method, you could choose between a couple different animation styles (fade and slide).

Comment: see this may be helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197260/hide-status-bar-while-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing was never right. You should not be talking to the shared application. It is the *top-level view controller* that is in charge of the status bar visibility, through the value of its `prefersStatusBarHidden` property.

The following snippet demonstrates how the *top-level view controller* can toggle status bar visibility with animation (in response to the tapping of a button, for demonstration purposes):

```
var hide = false
override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return self.hide
}
@IBAction func doButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.hide = !self.hide
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0.4) {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The same is true of `.fade` and `.slide`; these are to be given as the value of the *top level view controller's* override of the `preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation` property.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I've tried what you've suggested and while `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` is being called I still don't get the animation.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. I was missing "View controller-based status bar appearance" = "YES" from the .plist file.

Comment: Odd that you would need that, as it is the default. That code work fine for me without it (in a new vanilla project).