# Hide status bar whenever nav bar is hidden - SWIFT iOS8

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationbar

How can I had the status bar whenever the view is scrolling with:

```
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

or if not hide the status bar, how can I keep my status bar from overlaying my view?

ty awesome stackoverflow community

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent status bar from overlapping content with hidesBarsOnSwipe set on UINavigationController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870382/how-to-prevent-status-bar-from-overlapping-content-with-hidesbarsonswipe-set-on)

Comment: @MichałCiuba I was hoping I'd get it on swift rather than objective C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry if this answer is a little late, but here is one way to do it.

Use the prefersStatusBarHidden() method within your view controller.

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    if self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == true {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Basically says that when the Nav bar is hidden, then the status bar is too and vice versa.

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted (twice) without explanation, this is the correct answer, thanks for helping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26007878 this answer didn't work until i found this about "View controller-based status bar appearance" = "YES"

Answer (score 6):

A Swift 3 elegant solution:

```
open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden ?? false
}
```