# how to add/show toolbar below status bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my iOS application, I am adding functionality for collapsing toolbar when table view scrolls. But when toolbar moves above along y axis, I got following result (toolbar contents mixing with status bar contents).

[image]

```
@interface ListViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelPageTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat previousScrollViewYOffset;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *toolbarTop;

@end

@implementation ListViewController

//- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
//{
//    CGRect frame = self.toolbars.frame;
//    CGFloat size = frame.size.height - 21;
//    CGFloat framePercentageHidden = ((20 - frame.origin.y) / (frame.size.height - 1));
//    CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
//    CGFloat scrollDiff = scrollOffset - self.previousScrollViewYOffset;
//    CGFloat scrollHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
//    
//    NSLog(@"scrollView.frame - %@", NSStringFromCGRect(scrollView.frame));
//    NSLog(@"scrollView.contentInset - %@", NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(scrollView.contentInset));
//    
//    CGFloat scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom;
//    
//    if (scrollOffset <= -scrollView.contentInset.top) {
//        frame.origin.y = 20;
//    } else if ((scrollOffset + scrollHeight) >= scrollContentSizeHeight) {
//        frame.origin.y = -size;
//    } else {
//        frame.origin.y = MIN(20, MAX(-size, frame.origin.y - scrollDiff));
//    }
//    
//    [self.toolbars setFrame:frame];
//    [self updateBarButtonItems:(1 - framePercentageHidden)];
//    self.previousScrollViewYOffset = scrollOffset;
//}
//
//- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
//{
//    [self stoppedScrolling];
//}
//
//- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
//                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
//{
//    if (!decelerate) {
//        [self stoppedScrolling];
//    }
//}
//
//- (void)stoppedScrolling
//{
//    CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
//    if (frame.origin.y < 20) {
//        [self animateNavBarTo:-(frame.size.height - 21)];
//    }
//}
//
//- (void)updateBarButtonItems:(CGFloat)alpha
//{
//    self.buttonDismiss.customView.alpha = alpha;
//    self.labelPageTitle.alpha = alpha;
//    self.toolbars.tintColor = [self.toolbars.tintColor colorWithAlphaComponent:alpha];
//}
//
//- (void)animateNavBarTo:(CGFloat)y
//{
//    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
//        CGRect frame = self.toolbars.frame;
//        CGFloat alpha = (frame.origin.y >= y ? 0 : 1);
//        frame.origin.y = y;
//        [self.toolbars setFrame:frame];
//        [self updateBarButtonItems:alpha];
//    }];
//}

#pragma mark - view controllers life cycle methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    _toolbarTop.constant = -34;
    [self.listTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.listTableView setDelegate:self];

    [Utils updateLabelFontSize:self.labelPageTitle ForInitialHeight:22 andInitialSize:21];

    [self.labelPageTitle setText:@"My Category"/*self.productCategory*/];
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @Umair Afzal - I have posted code. please have a look

Comment: @Sanket, Why not use UINavigationController?

Comment: [UIBarPositioningDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarpositioningdelegate)

Comment: you shold use `navigation controller` or `UIView` if you don't want navigationbar!  why are you using `toolbar` ?

Comment: @0yeoj & Lion - in my app I have some complex behaviour of view controller containments. So I preferably avoid using navigation controller

Comment: @Desdenova - an you please explain in detail

Comment: with which element you have pinned your `top constraint` ??? I mean the constrain : `toolbarTop`

Comment: @Sanket Delegate your tool bar to your view controller. Something like `myToolbar.delegate = self`, then implement the linked delegate method and return `. topAttached` for bar position.

Comment: @Lion - yes From Toolbar.Top to TopLayoutGuide.Bottom

Comment: make it from `super view` instead `TopLayoutGuide.Bottom` and your issue will be solved i think! so your constraint should be bettween : `yourToolbar.top and your Superview.Top`

Comment: @Lion - sir can you please explain me. I didn't get the meaning of "from superview"

Comment: @Lion - Sir I tried this but not being able to gind option for Superview.Top. I have attached one screenshot. Please go through it once. My toolbar is subview of main view

Comment: remove this constraint first and pinned again! at that time you will get option! your constraint should be like as i have explain above and your constant should be `0`!

Comment: @Lion - Sir, I only able to apply constraints with respect to top layout guide. See above screenshot. Superview.top is not available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after playing for 4-5 hours, I come across the solution. First of all thanks to @Lion & @Desdenova for help.

Here is the link where I found some hint.

[iOS8: How do I make statusBar opaque after navigationBar is hidden using hidesBarsOnSwipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119720/ios8-how-do-i-make-statusbar-opaque-after-navigationbar-is-hidden-using-hidesba)

as per suggestions in the post I just assigned one UIView at status bar frame with same color of toolbar tint.

**Here is my updated code in view did load. Remaining is the same**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
//        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
//    
//    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
//    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    _toolbarTop.constant = -34;
    [self.listTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.listTableView setDelegate:self];

    //let topBar = UIView(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame)
    UIView *statusBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]];
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
    [self.view addSubview:statusBarView];

    [Utils updateLabelFontSize:self.labelPageTitle ForInitialHeight:22 andInitialSize:21];

    [self.labelPageTitle setText:@"My Category"/*self.productCategory*/];
}
```

**Final Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not pin constraint from `TopLayoutGuide.Bottom`, instead pin it with `superview's top`. You your `toolbar's top` should be pinned with `superview's top`. Check the below screenshot,

[image]

Comment: Yes sir now I got. This time I placed correctly.  but the same problem still exists.

Comment: What you want to achieve ?  do you want to hide tool bar ? or just want to drag your tool bar up? and what is the height of your toolbar and what is the `y` position of your toolbar ?

Comment: myToolbarFrame = ((0, 20),(widthOfView, 44))

Comment: for achieving my purpose, I'm following this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819165/imitate-ios-7-facebook-hide-show-expanding-contracting-navigation-bar

but I am changing the code for toolbar instead of navigation controller's navigation bar

Comment: I want to clone facebook iOS app's toolbar's behaviour. On scroll, I want "hide/show the toolbar at a rate that is proportional to the rate of the drag". Also I want to "fade the toolbar and its items as the bar shrinks." But when toolbar moves upwards, its contents mixed with status bar contents

Comment: replace " _toolbarTop.constant = -34;"  with  `"_toolbarTop.constant = -64;"

Comment: itmoving my toolbar from out of the scope of superview. but when I move slowly, I can see the effect of overlapping toolbar with status bar

Comment: then what you want ? do you not  want to hide or moved it completely ?

Comment: I want to clone facebook iOS app's toolbar's behaviour. On scroll, I want "hide/show the toolbar at a rate that is proportional to the rate of the drag". Also I want to "fade the toolbar and its items as the bar shrinks." But when toolbar moves upwards, its contents mixed with status bar contents. So I want to put toolbar below status bar

Comment: Sir Finally found some workaround to this problem. I have posted in answers section. Please have a look. If any corrections or further problems in future with this solution, then please let me know