# Hide navigation bar when scrolling without hiding the status bar and its background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to hide the navigation bar when scrolling down in a UITableView. However, i don't want to hide the status bar and its background color. (ex: the navigation bar background color is blue, i want the status bar background color to remain the same, when the navigation bar is hidden).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870382/how-to-prevent-status-bar-from-overlapping-content-with-hidesbarsonswipe-set-on?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Comment: is solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**please add this method**

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

 }
```

**in swift**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) 
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in doing this, the background of the status bar is removed too...

Comment: you can try add view to your controller, constrained to top of the superview(not top layout guide!) with `height = 20` and background you needed

Comment: than you can go with @KKRocks answer