# Swift iOS -NavigationBar hidesBarsOnSwipe never reappears when setting CollectionView Frame under Status Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have a tabBar with a programmatic CollectionView inside a NavigationController. I noticed that when swiping up the CollectionView cells would show under the status bar. To get around it when I configured the frame for the CollectionView I used `view.frame.origin.y + 20` where `20` is the height of the status bar. The reason I did that is because I used `view.frame.size.height - tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height` to prevent the cells from showing underneath the tabBar and it worked.

I also wanted to hide the navBar on swipe so in ViewDidLoad I set `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`.

**The problem is** when swiping up the navBar hides on swipe and the cells no longer show underneath the statusBar **but when swiping down the navBar never comes back**. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.title = "Home"

        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

        configureCollectionView()
}

func configureCollectionView(){

        let frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x,
                       y: view.frame.origin.y + 20, // here is where I add + 20 for the statusBar's height
                       width: view.frame.size.width,
                       height: view.frame.size.height - tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.size.height) // here is where I subtracted the tabBar's height (- 49)

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(HomeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: homeCell)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a simple fix. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26007878/4833705).

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden ?? false
}
```

And be sure you have "View controller-based status bar appearance" = "YES" in your application .plist file.